# batch script to delete characters in text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file, I need to delete the characters after 90 from left, I'm looking for a automation, please help!

H0000300000011060040517171959
Line 1 : D41799771000000011550000000370004871700001CHARLEYS GRILLED SUBS                          **1234567898-03052017**

Line 2 : D41799771000000011440000000496007091700001WALLSTREET                                      **1234567740-01052017**

Line 3 : D4179977100000001155000000022232323251700001KFC                              **1234568476-03052017**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    set "line=!line:~0,-91!"
    echo !line! ) > list.txt
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  Show your own code, describe your failures, and ask a precise question beyond *"please help!"*

Comment: I count each of those lines as less than 90-characters long.  I think the entire line should be preserved.

Comment: I'm using below script, however am able to delete the characters but it deletes the first line completely

Comment: @echo off &setlocal
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:~0,-91!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>list.txt

Comment: this is my first line : H0000300000011060040517171959

Comment: ***No.*** Put your script *in your question*, properly formatted.  No one can read that script in a comment!

Answer (score 0):

If you want 90 characters:

```
set "line=!line:~,90!"
```

I don't know why you put a -91 in there?

The syntax is:

```
![VARIABLE]:~,[Stop after this many characters]!
```

Comment: Thank you so much @abelenky, it worked for me...how can I save this file as test_YYYYMMDD.txt

Comment: also if i could send email notification once the new file is generated using smtp relay!

Comment: Both of those are WAY beyond the scope of the original question.  You asked a question, you got an answer.